# Change Text if Matches?

Tags: vba, excel

Right now I have this copying data from Worksheet 1 Column B.

I want it so that it doesn't copy it it just puts Completed if it says Completed or Not Completed if it says Not Completed. Right now it copies the extra info I have next to Completed.

```
With Sheets("Worksheet 2")
    .Range("B1").Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'WorkSheet 1'!A:B,2,0))," & """""" & ",VLOOKUP(A1,'Worksheet 1'!A:B,2,0))"
    .Range("B1").Copy Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

Comment: What do you mean you want it to say Completed or Not Completed? What does the spread sheet look like ?

Comment: Does the text in the cell you are copying from always begin with "Completed"/"Not Completed" or could they appear anywhere in the text?

Answer (score 0):

So I think this will work for you, but let me know if it doesn't do what you're asking.  On a side note,  `iferror(...,"error value")` is a good replacement for `if(iserror(...,"error value",...)`.  It saves you from having to type your test condition twice.

```
With Sheets("Worksheet 2")
    .Range("B1").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(IFERROR(FIND(""Not Completed"",VLOOKUP(A1,'WorkSheet 1'!A:B,2,0)),0),""Not Completed"",IF(IFERROR(FIND(""Completed"",VLOOKUP(A1,'WorkSheet 1'!A:B,2,0)),""""),""Completed"","""")),"""")"
    .Range("B1").Copy Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
```

Comment: That is amazing sir! It all works, but apparently it has some additional information in the 4000+ rows that I did not see. So is there anyway that if it says Completed, then it will show y and if it is not completed or anything else is there, that it would just put n?

Comment: Yes you can do that.  The structure of this formula is nested in such a way that first you look for "Not Completed" and if that isn't there you then check for "Completed" (otherwise both would be true for this IF statement). Last you want anything else to show up as "N".  Hence "N" has to go in two spots and "Y" in one.  Here is the formula that does that:

.Range("B1").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(IFERROR(FIND(""Not Completed"",VLOOKUP(A1,'WorkSheet 1'!A:B,2,0)),0),""N"",IF(IFERROR(FIND(""Completed"",VLOOKUP(A1,'WorkSheet 1'!A:B,2,0)),""""),""Y"","""")),""N"")"